# jQuery Prevent Loading same image twice in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a good bit of jQuery to create a CSS fade effect on a website. It works really well. But as it only has 4 images in the array, It is quite likely loading the same image twice in a row.

What can I add to prevent this?

My current jQuery code is as follows :

```
// Playthrough Background Images
var imgArray = ['http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner1.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner2.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner3.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner4.jpg'
]
var nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)] + ")";

$('#header.home-page').css("background-image", nextBG);

setInterval(function(){
    nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)] + ")";
    $('#header.home-page').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", nextBG).fadeIn('fast'); })
}, 4000); // 4 second interval
```

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: You can always rotate these images in order instead of randomly

Comment: Thats not a bad shout either. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Just set a counter starting at 1, and increase it every time you show an image. Make sure to reset the counter to 1 when you reach 4. See the answer by friedi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show your images one after another (and repeat this the whole time):

```
var counter = 0;

// Playthrough Background Images
var imgArray = ['http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner1.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner2.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner3.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner4.jpg'
]
var nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[counter] + ")";

$('#header.home-page').css("background-image", nextBG);

setInterval(function(){
    counter++;
    nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[counter % imgArray.length] + ")";
    $('#header.home-page').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", nextBG).fadeIn('fast'); })
}, 4000); // 4 second interval
```

or choose randomly:

```
// Playthrough Background Images
var imgArray = ['http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner1.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner2.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img//home/banner3.jpg',
    'http://www.jesmonddenehouse.co.uk/addons/shared_addons/themes/jesmonddene/img/home/banner4.jpg'
]
var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
var nextBG = "url(" + imgArray[current] + ")";

$('#header.home-page').css("background-image", nextBG);

setInterval(function(){
    var copy = imgArray.slice(0); // make copy
    copy.splice(current, 1); // remove current
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    nextBG = "url(" + copy[current] + ")";
    $('#header.home-page').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", nextBG).fadeIn('fast'); })
}, 4000); // 4 second interval
```

Comment: Thanks for both options @friedi The only problem I have now is that its opening that first image twice at the beginning. This is on the play through in sequential order.